# Tkinter and Python3 - How Can I justify a multiple lines text in a label widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a text composed by multiple lines in a ttk label. by default the text is displayed from the left border to right one without any kind of "justify" option. my goal is spread the text on all the label. I don't want to align the text on the right, on the left, on the center, etc.. I want to justify it, exatly when you justify a text in Microsoft Word. how can I reach my goal?

Comment: You can insert space between words to expand each line to the desired width.

Comment: ciao acw1668! I could but It's a workaround and not a solution. in addition it's not scalable. If exists, I would prefer to use an automatic solution, already integrated in tkinter.

Comment: As you said, there is no such feature in `Label` widget, then you should think about other options.

Comment: surfing on internet I can't find the right solution. maybe other guys from the community can help us.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tkinter.ScrolledText` module:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import *

win = Tk()

TEXT="""I have a text composed by multiple lines in a ttk label.
by default the text is displayed from the left border to right one without any kind of "justify" option.
My goal is spread the text on all the label. I don't want to align the text on the right, on the left, on the center, etc..
I want to justify it, exatly when you justify a text in Microsoft Word. how can I reach my goal?"""

text = ScrolledText(win, width=80, height=41, wrap=WORD) # create text zone
text.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH) # pack it in the entire window
text.insert(1.0, TEXT)

win.mainloop()
```

With adding `tkinter.filedialog`, you can make a real Notepad !

The Python IDLE was actually made like that.